# 2D std::vector replace values - need for delete to avoid memory leaks?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a 2D vector, and I want all the `int` values to be replaced by *zeros*.

Although this code seems to work, I was wondering:

- Do I needed to delete the old vector before reassigning it (at line 5), since there is a copy of `std::vector<int>` stored in `line`?
- Is it the best way to replace values (using iterators)?

Code:

```
for (std::vector< std::vector<int> >::iterator it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it)
{
  std::vector<int> line = *it;
  std::fill(line.begin(), line.end(), 0);
  *it = line; // line 5
}
```

I want to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Since you don't call `new`, you don't need `delete`. But you should probably make `line` a reference to avoid unnecessary copies.

Comment: Suppose simplest would be just having `std::fill(it->begin(), it->end(), 0);`...

Comment: Depends on what you are doing with your vectors, but possibly mapping the two dimensions on a 1D array is more efficient (`auto getValue(r, c) { return v[r*columns + c]; }`). Retaining `v[r][c]` syntax would still be possible, but requries some extra work (including an intermediate class).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to `delete` anything in your code sice you didn't create something with `new`.

If you want too do all this in a single line you can use [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) and `std::fill`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
std::vector<std::vector<int>> a;

// set every element in two dimensional vector to 5
std::for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), [](std::vector<int> &x){std::fill(x.begin(), x.end(), 5);});
```

---

**Addendum related to your comment:**
Yes, your original vector is stored on the stack. Since you don't pass a custom allocator, the vector will use the [`std::allocator`](https://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) to allocate its elements (which in your case are vectors of int). The `std::allocator` allocates these elements in dynamic memory aka the heap but you don't need to worry about freeing or deleting this memory because it is handeled by the internals of the vector. This means that the memory is deleted at the latest if the destructor of the vector is called (e.g. because it goes out of scope) or possibly earlier if you change the size of the vector.

Comment: I was wondering, since I push_back a vector of int, how is it stored ? I mean the original vector is stored on the stack since it is declared inside a class method, right?, but then does std::vector deal with heap memory allocation ? does it do garbage collecting ?

Comment: See edit of my answer (was to long to answer as a comment).